# Java EE dinamic web projeto

Tags: java-ee-8

I don't know how to fix this error anymore

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head></h:head>

<body> 

    <h1>Java Enterprise Edition</h1>
    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="Nome: "/>
        <h:inputText value="#{formularioMB.nome}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Executar" action="#{formularioMB.executar}" />
    
    </h:form>

</body> 
</html>
```

```
package br.nead.ads.jee.mb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class FormularioMB implements Serializable{
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private String nome;
    
    public FormularioMB()
    {
        System.out.println("Criando uma instancia de exemploMB");
        
    }
    
    public void setNome(String nome)
    {
        System.out.println("SetNome "+nome);
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getNome()
    {
        System.out.println("GetNome "+nome);
        return nome;
    }
    
    public void executar()
    {
        System.out.println("Invocando metodo executar()...");
        System.out.println("Nome digitado: " + nome);
    }

}
```

I already tried using @managetbeans but it didn't work either.

this is the error that is causing

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: /index.xhtml @13,46 value="#{formularioMB.nome}": Destino inacessível, identificador 'formularioMB' resolvido como nulo
    em javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:725)
    em javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    em io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
    em io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    em org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    em io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    em io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    em io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    em io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    em io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    em io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    em io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    em org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    em io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    em org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    em io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
    em io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    em io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    em org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    em org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    em org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    em org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    em org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    em org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
    em io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
    em io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
    em io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    em org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    em org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    em org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    em org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    em java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Causado por: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @13,46 value="#{formularioMB.nome}": Destino inacessível, identificador 'formularioMB' resolvido como nulo
    em com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:64)
    em com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:71)
    em javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1105)
    em javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:1006)
    em javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1317)
    em javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:733)
    em javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:229)
    em javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:921)
    em javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1309)
    em com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:53)
    em com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    em com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
    em javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
    ... mais 49
Causado por: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identificador 'formularioMB' resolvido como nulo
    em com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:149)
    em com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:61)
    em com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:177)
    em org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
    em org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
    em com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:62)
    ... 61 mais
```

I've already done several searches but nothing solved it, I copied this code exactly the same from the college book, but it's giving me an error.

any help I appreciate it

Comment: Please provide english translation to the error message as Stackoverflow is an English-only site and the error message is an important context here